# Reformatting endnotes in memoir

Tags: memoir, endnotes, pagenote

I'm pretty new to TeX and was hoping you might be able to help me.

I'm using the "memoir" class and using \makepagenote and \notepageref for my end note citations. Using these two commands, the following pagenote:

\pagenote[When I wrote this...]{It refers to this citation.}

Turns out like this:

[When I wrote this...] (page x) It refers to this citation.

I'd like to slightly reconfigure it so it instead appears like this:

x: **When I wrote this...** It refers to this citation.

So, that means three tweaks:

1. Move the page number to the beginning of the end note.
2. Remove the word "page" and replace the parentheses around the page number with a single colon after the page number.
3. Bold the reference text and remove the square brackets around it.

(Also, as a bonus, if there's a way to have it put two line breaks after each reference, that would be sweet! Right now, I'm manually adding \* to the end of every citation, but it would be nice if I didn't have to.)

Many thanks for your help! Truly appreciate it!

Comment: I had an answer for you for an earlier version of `memoir` but it doesn't work with the current version. I have alerted the current maintainer to your difficulty.

Comment: As always on the site, it helps a lot if you provide a minimal example we can work with.

Comment: Also: what should happen if you use `\pagenote` without `[]` (or are you always doing that?)

Comment: I do not quote understand your bonus. How does page notes relate to citations?

Answer (score 2):

Unless I have misunderstood your question this does what you want.

- first we change how the \startnoteentrystart typesets its contents, thus moving the page references up front.
- next we redefine three formatting macros
- as for your bonus, that can be done via `\postnoteinnotes`

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\makepagenote
\notepageref
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\startnoteentrystart[4]{%
  \prenoteinnotes%
  \pageinnotes{#3}%<-- moved this up
  \noteidinnotes{#1}{#2}%
  \@ifmtarg{#2}{\phantomsection\def\@currentlabel{#1}}{}%
  \pagenoteanchor{#4}%
  \prenotetext%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\idtextinnotes}[1]{\textbf{#1}\space}
\renewcommand*{\printpageinnotes}[1]{\pageref{#1}:\space}
% just if hyperref is used
\renewcommand\printpageinnoteshyperref[1]{\pageref{#1}:\space}
\renewcommand{\postnoteinnotes}{\par\bigskip}

\begin{document}

test\pagenote[When I wrote this...]{It refers to this citation.}
test\pagenote[Something else...]{Some text}


\printpagenotes


\end{document}
```