# Page notes with no mark in text and no number in notes for one chapter in memoir

Tags: memoir, endnotes, pagenote

I am transcribing a document into the `memoir` class that has a front matter "chapter" with a collection of epigraphs. Each epigraph has no page note mark in the text, but in the back matter Notes section there is an unnumbered list of references for the Epigraphs chapter, one reference for each quotation. Other main matter chapters have normal page notes with numerical marks in the text and numbered lists in the Notes chapter. I have achieved a `\pagenote` that temporarily does not put marks in the text, but how can I achieve an unnumbered list of references in `\printpagenotes` for one chapter only? MWE and my attempts below.

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makepagenote
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Epigraphs}
\let\orignotenumintext\notenumintext
\renewcommand*{\notenumintext}[1]{\relax} % don't print a page note mark
\lipsum[1]\pagenote{Cicero}\par
\lipsum[2]\pagenote{Augustus}
\let\notenumintext\orignotenumintext % restore original page note mark behavior
\mainmatter
\chapter{Body}
\lipsum[3-4]\pagenote{Caesar}
\backmatter
\printpagenotes
% results in:

% Notes
% Chapter 0 Epigraphs
% 1. Cicero
% 2. Augustus
% Chapter 1 Body
% 1. Caesar
\end{document}
```

In the above, I want to get rid of the `1.` and `2.` before `Cicero` and `Augustus`. I tried to override and then restore `\notenuminnotes` as I did with `\notenumintext`, but this did not produce the desired behavior. I guess `\notenuminnotes` is maybe not expanded until it's time to actually typeset the Notes chapter.

I also noticed in the `memoir` manual there is `\addtonotes`, but this command is more low-level and just splats some text into the `ent` file. So if you write `\addtonotes{Cicero}\addtonotes{Augustus}` you will not even get a line break. I'd like to use the usual `\pagenote` architecture if possible so I can play with the other commands like `\prenoteinnotes` etc. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makepagenote

\renewcommand{\idtextinnotes}[1]{}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Epigraphs}
\lipsum[1]\pagenote[\relax]{Cicero}\par
\lipsum[2]\pagenote[\relax]{Augustus}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Body}
\lipsum[3-4]\pagenote{Caesar}
\backmatter
\printpagenotes

\end{document}
```

For further customisation, perhaps the answer here can help: [Reformatting endnotes in memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500408/reformatting-endnotes-in-memoir)

Cf. also section "12.6.1 Changing the appearance" in `memoir` documentation.